# Middle-button scrolling on Thinkpad W540

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, scrolling

I just got a W540 today and found out the touchpad is different than the previous models.  While the previous models have three actual keys (left, middle, right), the new model has no key and the whole touchpad is a button.

In the old models you can scroll a page but holding the middle button and move the trackpoint.  Is it possible to do that on W540?

If not, is there anyway to enable "one-finger scrolling"?   That is, I want the whole touchpad to be a scrolling pad... as long as I move finger there it will scrolls.  Is that possible?

The system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have a w540 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. The default Unix behavior is he middle mouse button for pasting the contents of the clipboard.  If you want to set up scrolling check out this webpage on [how to configure the trackpoint](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint#Scrolling).

You can enable scrolling with one finger if you go to System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad and uncheck the "Two finger scroll" option.  This allows you to scroll vertically with one finger on the right edge of the touchpad (as is common from earlier model touchpads).

Two other resources I keep handy are Debian on [Thinkpad W540](https://gist.github.com/fbrozovic/9102118) (github.com), and the [W540 page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aW540) on ThinkWiki.